# Android Custom Listview unable to load items from internet

Tags: android

I have created an custom listview, that displays an image of an item and its details e.g description, price. The list works well on localhost but when change the url to my website domain, the it fails to load items- just displays a blank interface. Am using XML parsing, where the xml file is being created by PHP script that reads data from mysql database. I have checked my PHP scripts they working well and  XML file being written properly. Would anyone please tell why the list is unable to load items?

Comment: You need to post code and any errors you get for us to help you with your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked the image exists? Put the URL into your browser and see if it returns. If it does, then there will be an issue in your code preventing the Image being downloaded. This is not really an Android question, its more related to your web services I feel.